# Is there an Android app that allows to collect sound sleep data and export it to PC?

Tags: android, health

I have started using sleepbot Android app with "track sound" feature turned on, but am having a hard time getting access to sound data - I can only see it as a graph on the app itself. A recommendation for how a way to export it from the sleepbot  app, or another app that allows to do that would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the dashboard after login on their webapp provide what you require? [click on try it now](https://mysleepbot.com/tour) on this page for dashboard.

Comment: Try sleepasandroid and talk to the developer.  He might agree to do it.

Comment: 1. Why would you like this? 2. As mk117 said: Have you set SleepBot to sync with the SleepBot cloud service? Have you logged into [the service](http://www.mysleepbot.com/login)? Did this fulfill your needs?

Comment: 3. Tony French writes [here](http://sleepbot.uservoice.com/forums/123267-general/suggestions/5240812-add-an-option-to-export-the-actual-recording-so-th) that SleepBot retains full copies of each night's sound recording. (But I suspect that you may have to tweak SleepBot's "Settings > Sleep Tracking > Recording Threshold" setting first.) Have you tried using an Android file manager, such as OpenIntents File Manager, to access the recordings?